# ImageButton selector doesn't work?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am trying to make ImageButton for state of pressed, focused and normal. 
I've read introduction of ImageButton [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

I've saved selector XML file in /res/drawable/. Also set the `android:src="@drawable/my_selector"`.

my_selector.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_unfocus" /> <!-- default -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_onpress" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_onfocus" /> <!-- focused -->
</selector>
```

I think I've done correct ImageButton. But it didn't work for me.

What is wrong here ?

Please advice.

Comment: kenu.heo have good answer, you can accept it

Answer (score 7):

Item tags should be ordered.
So pressed first, focused, and the last is default item

Refer [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting it wrong.
Try this.

```
android:background="@drawable/your_selector_name"
```